# App loads repeats of the same article from News API (Swift)

Tags: ios, json, swift, networking

I am using an API from News API to load in science related articles. When I paste the https into google, it gives me all of the correct articles. However when I run the app, the app loads in repeats of the same article.

[Screen Shot From My App Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cszHv.png)

Also, the code can be found in the models and views folders on my git page. I would appreciate any help as this is one of my first projects!

Here is the code that creates the url and decodes the JSON.

```
func fetchData() {
    // 1. Create a URL
    if let url = URL(string: "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=gb&category=science&apiKey=7806d7a294994cd2af9d272bbfe4f334") {

        // 2. Create a URLsession
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

        // 3. Give the session a task
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                if let safeData = data {
                    do {
                        let results = try decoder.decode(Results.self, from: safeData)
                        // Update must happen on the main thread, not in the background
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                             self.posts = results.articles
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // 4. Start the task
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Here is the model for the JSON file

```
struct Results: Decodable {
    let articles: [Post]
}

struct Post: Decodable, Identifiable {
    let title, description, url, urlToImage: String
    let source: Source

    var id: String? {
        source.id
    }
}

struct Source: Decodable { 
    let id: String?
}
```

Finally, here is the code that displays all of the links

```
struct ContentView: View {

@ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        // for every single post in the post array
        List(networkManager.posts) { post in
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(url: post.url)) {
                VStack {
                    Text(post.title)
                        .bold()
                    HStack {
                            Text(post.description)
                                .padding(.top)
                        URLImage(URL(string: post.urlToImage)!) { proxy in
                            proxy.image
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        }
                        .frame(width:150)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Science Bite")
    }
        // This calls fetch data
        .onAppear {
            self.networkManager.fetchData()
    }
}
}
```

Additionally, here is the GitHub link:
[GitHub Link](https://github.com/ParisJacksonNewman/ScienceBite)

Comment: You should include relevant code here. Not the git link.

Comment: ^^^ is correct - post the relevanrt code sections, and make it easy for peple to help you.  Without seeing the code I'd guess the API returns data in batches and there is a cursor that needs to used with subsequent requests otherwise it'll just repeat the first batch of articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `source.id` to satisfy your `Post`'s conformance to `Identifiable` but if you look at the returned JSON you will see that several articles have a source id of `null`.  Also, even for articles with a non-null source id, the id is the id of the *source*, not a unique id for the article.

Since your data contained non-unique identifiers, the `List` mixed up items; specifically, when it found a subsequent row with an identifier of `null` it just re-used the existing row with the same identifier.

`url` is a better choice for `id` as you would expect each article to have a unique url. (You could also just use `UUID()`)

Once I changed your `Post` struct it works correctly:

```
struct Post: Decodable, Identifiable {
    let title, description, url, urlToImage: String
    let source: Source

    var id: String {
        url
    }
}
```